# Btee-index select query takes long time

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

My query is below:

```
WITH CTE AS(
         SELECT Id,
                SaleTime
         FROM   tbl_sales_log
         WHERE  saletime > ’2019 -06 -01 00:00:00’
                AND saletime < ’2019 -06 -30 23:59:59’
                AND centerid IN (708, 805, 432, 403)
                AND itemid IN (3, 6)
         ORDER BY
                saletime DESC limit 1000 offset 0
     ) 

SELECT Id,
       col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       col4,
       col5,
       col6,
       col7,
       col8,
       saletime
FROM   my_table_6 R
WHERE  R.id = ANY(
           SELECT Id
           FROM   CTE limit 1000
       )
       AND R.saletime > ’2019 -06 -01 00:00:00’
       AND R.saletime < ’2019 -06 -30 23:59:59’
ORDER BY
       R.saletime DESC limit 1000;
```

Explain (analyze,buffers) is below:

[image: Explain statement picture]

`my_table_6` has 35 million records. It has a btree-index for the column `Id`.

When I select just 1000 records it takes almost 30 seconds.

How can I optimize it?

Note: PostgreSQL 12 server is running on Windows.

CTE query executed within 500 millisecond, but querying from `my_table_6` takes more time. I have checked this many times.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Please **never** post screenshots for reasons outlined [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). There are some tips on asking questions here on my profile - you might want to take a look? Help us to help you - these forums are a great resource and you will get all the more out of them if you follow the guidelines - Best...

Comment: Also, please post the DDL for all tables referred to in your query.

Comment: What indexes do you have?  Perhaps `(SaleTime, Id)` in that order?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a **covering index** for your **CTE** query on the `my_table_6` table, so the PostgreSQL engine is doing its best by scanning the closest index it can find.

Create an index on the `my_table_6` table that covers `id` and `saletime`, and then recheck the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is showing an **index seek** operation instead of **index scan**.

Also why not try re-writing your query in a more relational way like this, to see if you get a better query plan:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
     SELECT Id,
            SaleTime
     FROM   tbl_sales_log
     WHERE  saletime > ’2019 -06 -01 00:00:00’
            AND saletime < ’2019 -06 -30 23:59:59’
            AND centerid IN (708, 805, 432, 403)
            AND itemid IN (3, 6)
     ORDER BY
            saletime DESC limit 1000 offset 0
) 

SELECT Id,
       col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       col4,
       col5,
       col6,
       col7,
       col8,
       saletime
FROM my_table_6 R
INNER JOIN CTE C
    ON R.id = C.id
WHERE  R.saletime > ’2019 -06 -01 00:00:00’
       AND R.saletime < ’2019 -06 -30 23:59:59’
ORDER BY
       R.saletime DESC limit 1000;
```

Comment: CTE query executed with in 500 millisecond, but querying from my_table_6 only takes more time.I have checked many times

Comment: @nikithapalani Sorry it was hard to read the screenshot of your `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (please try to include the actual text next time). Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't post execution plans as screen shots.

The problem is that the index scan on `my_table_6` takes 26.5 milliseconds on average and is executed 1000 times.

Try `VACUUM` on the table to remove dead rows. If the index is bloated, `REINDEX` might help.